# Is there an efficient/optimal way to transfer data from BigQuery table to Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, google-bigquery, data-migration, reindex

I have about 45GB of data in my BigQuery that I want to transfer to Elasticsearch. Currently, I am fetching rows from my BigQuery table as JSON then indexing them into Elasticsearch. The whole process took about 2 weeks to complete. I just wanted to know if there is a better and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: the 45GB is single file or chunk of file

Comment: It is chunk of file.

Comment: try to use generator

Comment: @ThangarajanPannerselvam Could you please elaborate on that. I am not much familiar with generator.

Comment: Hi! I would like to ask you to take a look for following thread  in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252484/elastic-search-with-google-big-query where you can find different scenarios. Let me know if it's sufficient for your needs.